# How can I get a dict value by another dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to get dict1 value by using a dict2 but I'm getting an error msg

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
dict1 = {"1": "Ali","2": "21","3": "Kuwait"}
dict2 = {"Name": "1","Age": "2","City": "Kuwait"}
print(dict1['dict2['Name']'])
```

Comment: If you're going to put single quotes in a string, the string needs to be using either double quotes or triple single quotes. But do you actually want the key to be a string?

Comment: remove the quotes

Comment: It is syntax error because you have sandwiched `Name` between two strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want: `print(dict1[dict2['Name']])`